# Arzoo Bus booking API integration using PHP Curl and XML

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I'm working on Bus API of arzoo. The server must receive the posted data in simple POST Request. To achieve this i'm using PHP cURL. In the API Document it is clearly mention that the data should be sent in the following format:

```
<BusRequest>
<source>HYDERABAD</source>
<dest>BANGALORE</dest>
<dep_date>25-Mar-2016</dep_date>
<PartnerId>ID of the partner given by arzoo</PartnerId>
<Clientid>ID of the client given by arzoo</Clientid>
<Clientpassword>Client password given by arzoo</Clientpassword>
<Clienttype>ArzooBUSWS1.0</Clienttype>
</BusRequest>
```

My PHP cURL code is as follows:

```
$input_xml = '<BusRequest>
                <source>Ernakulam</source>
                <dest>Kozhikode</dest>
                <dep_date>15-Nov-2017</dep_date>
                <PartnerId>partner</PartnerId>
                <Clientid>clientid</Clientid>
                <Clientpassword>password</Clientpassword>
                <Clienttype>clienttype</Clienttype>
                </BusRequest>';

    $url = "url";      
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "xmlRequest=" . $input_xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I'm not getting any valid xml as response.Am i doing anything wrong ?. Your reply will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Could you share what you are getting as the response, it may help.

Comment: I'm getting an invalid string '80InzwMcWbDoYT....'. I can't figure out why they are giving such response. Thanks .

Comment: Finally the problem solved. The API Providers was not giving a valid response.